# Ensuring users get the correct information from a mysql statement?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I am trying to build a simple buying and selling website (only with pretend money) for a project I am working on.

Users can have money in their hand or in their virtual bank, so to speak. I am using this transaction when users deposit money from their hand into their account wrapped in a PHP if statement:

```
if ($_POST['deposit'] > 0 && $_POST['deposit'] <= $user['money']) {
     $dbc -> beginTransaction();
     $dbc -> query("SELECT id FROM items WHERE id = " . $user['id'] . " FOR UPDATE LIMIT 1");
     $q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE items SET money = money-?, bank = bank+?");
     $q -> execute(array($_POST['deposit'], $_POST['deposit']));
     $dbc -> commit();
}
```

Other accounts can also view users' information such as their amount of money. If an account views a user's data just as he is depositing money into his account, will the above query ensure that they get the correct consistent data from mySQL?

I get all the information from an account by using;

```
$dbc -> query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = " . $account['id'] . ");
```

If an account accesses the user's data just as he is depositing money, will the mySQL query wait for the new updated rows? I would like to just make sure all my queries are consistent across my project

Also is it ok to use a LIMIT 1 on the SELECT FOR UPDATE query?

Answer (score 0):

Use InnoDB for transactional integrity, and you'll get what you want.

As far as `LIMIT 1` goes, you would be very wise indeed to design your table so it's impossible to have more than one row selected for update, by using a primary key to select.